# Partial search in python tkinter doesn't work

Tags: python, tkinter, search-box

I've got a problem with a part of my code. It's about partial searching in treeview. I found here on stack overflow partial search method and tried to use with my code. It does't work - It doesn't give any results. Code here below:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
root = Tk()
sv = StringVar()
ids = []
names = []
def add():
    names = tree.insert("",END,values=(e0.get(),e1.get(),e2.get(),e3.get()))

for i in range(len(names)):
    ids.append(tree.insert("", "end", text=names[i]))
 
def command(*args):
    selections = []
    for i in range(len(names)):
        if entry.get() != "" and entry.get() == names[i][:len(entry.get())]:
            selections.append(ids[i])
        tree.selection_set(selections)
sv.trace("w", command)
entry = Entry(root, textvariable=sv,width=13)
entry.grid(row=2,column=1,rowspan=3,sticky=W)
e0 = Entry(root,width=15)
e0.grid(row=0,column=1,rowspan=1,sticky=W)
e1 = Entry(root,width=15)
e1.grid(row=0,column=1,rowspan=2,sticky=W)
e2 = Entry(root,width=15)
e2.grid(row=0,column=1,rowspan=3,sticky=W)
e3 = Entry(root,width=15)
e3.grid(row=0,column=1,rowspan=4,sticky=W)
 
btn1 = Button(root,text="add",width=5,command=add)
btn1.grid(row =0,column=0,rowspan=5)
lb1 = Label(root,text="serial num:")
lb1.grid(row =0,column=0,rowspan=1)
lb2 = Label(root,text="medicine\nname ")
lb2.grid(row =0,column=0,rowspan=2)
lb3 = Label(root,text="quatity")
lb3.grid(row =0,column=0,rowspan=3)
lb4 = Label(root,text="expiry Date")
lb4.grid(row =0,column=0,rowspan=4)
lb4 = Label(root,text="search box")
lb4.grid(row =1,column=0,rowspan=6)
#treeview
tree = ttk.Treeview(root,height=25)
tree["columns"]=("one","two","three","four")
tree.column("one",width=120)
tree.column("two",width=160)
tree.column("three",width=130)
tree.column("four",width=160)
tree.heading("one", text="Numer seryjny leku")
tree.heading("two", text="Nazwa Leku")
tree.heading("three", text="Ampułki/Tabletki")
tree.heading("four",text="Data ważności")
tree["show"]="headings"
tree.grid(row=0,column=2,rowspan=6,pady=20)
root.geometry("840x580")
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `names` is not defined. You should put a similar line to the following one in the beginning of your code:

```
names = []
```

On the other hand, you have to declare the command function as follows to make it work, since the trace callback expects at least three arguments:

```
def command(*args):
```

By the way, if you do not want to loose the data in variable `names`, I would transform your code in a class-oriented way, such as the following one:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
root = Tk()
sv = StringVar()
ids = []


class Tree():
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.names = []
        sv.trace("w", self.command)
        self.entry = Entry(root, textvariable=sv, width=13)
        self.entry.grid(row=2,column=1,rowspan=3,sticky=W)
        self.e0 = Entry(root,width=15)
        self.e0.grid(row=0,column=1,rowspan=1,sticky=W)
        self.e1 = Entry(root,width=15)
        self.e1.grid(row=0,column=1,rowspan=2,sticky=W)
        self.e2 = Entry(root,width=15)
        self.e2.grid(row=0,column=1,rowspan=3,sticky=W)
        self.e3 = Entry(root,width=15)
        self.e3.grid(row=0,column=1,rowspan=4,sticky=W)
        
        self.btn1 = Button(root,text="add",width=5,command=self.add)
        self.btn1.grid(row =0,column=0,rowspan=5)
        self.lb1 = Label(root,text="serial num:")
        self.lb1.grid(row =0,column=0,rowspan=1)
        self.lb2 = Label(root,text="medicine\nname ")
        self.lb2.grid(row =0,column=0,rowspan=2)
        self.lb3 = Label(root,text="quatity")
        self.lb3.grid(row =0,column=0,rowspan=3)
        self.lb4 = Label(root,text="expiry Date")
        self.lb4.grid(row =0,column=0,rowspan=4)
        self.lb4 = Label(root,text="search box")
        self.lb4.grid(row =1,column=0,rowspan=6)
        #treeview
        self.tree = ttk.Treeview(root,height=25)
        self.tree["columns"]=("one","two","three","four")
        self.tree.column("one",width=120)
        self.tree.column("two",width=160)
        self.tree.column("three",width=130)
        self.tree.column("four",width=160)
        self.tree.heading("one", text="Numer seryjny leku")
        self.tree.heading("two", text="Nazwa Leku")
        self.tree.heading("three", text="Ampułki/Tabletki")
        self.tree.heading("four",text="Data ważności")
        self.tree["show"]="headings"
        self.tree.grid(row=0,column=2,rowspan=6,pady=20)
    
    def add(self):
        self.names = self.tree.insert("",END,values=(self.e0.get(),self.e1.get(),self.e2.get(),self.e3.get()))

        for i in range(len(self.names)):
            ids.append(self.tree.insert("", "end", text=self.names[i]))
    
    def command(self, *args):
        selections = []
        for i in range(len(self.names)):
            if self.entry.get() != "" and self.entry.get() == self.names[i][:len(self.entry.get())]:
                selections.append(ids[i])
            self.tree.selection_set(selections)

tree = Tree(root)
root.geometry("840x580")
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Great that works. But when I type lower or capital words it doesn't match any results when a word starts with other size of letter.

Comment: To get correctly the values of a treeview in tkinter, you should use something like:             for line in self.tree.get_children():
                for value in self.tree.item(line)['values']:
                    print(value)

Comment: Otherwise, you are putting just the name of the tree row under names, and not the actual values